# Setup different target for using different constant in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I know maybe a question is duplicated, but where I can check information. How to setup different targets to build with different bundle name etc.

Right now I know of course how to create different targets in Xcode, it is very simple to copy it from example from first target that was created automatically when I created project.

But I also have Constant.h and Constant.m files. I want to handle constants depend on which target I build for.

Let's say when build for target A I need to setup `NSString const *toEmail = @"a@test.com"`, but in case if I build for the target B then `toEmail = @"b@test";`

Do I need to create two difference Constant files say ConstantA.m and ConstantB.m or maybe there is another best practice here. I don't want to recreate a wheel )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I setup Preprocessor Macro in target build settings for just one target. (For Example: TARGET_B)

[image: Build Settings]

And in code i check using

```
// Check if it's target B:
#if TARGET_B
NSString const *toEmail = @"b@test.com"
#else
NSString const *toEmail = @"a@test.com"
#end
```

Comment: thank you for answer, so macro as well has the same name as my target?

Comment: Name can be anything. But you set it in just one target .

Comment: no i mean about macros so there ara just this line if my_target_a